# Displaying both key and value in 2 separate table columns in jsx from an array of objects in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, string-interpolation

I found a work around in Hooks for creating a table that displays 2 columns 'Word' and 'Count' in jsx by using an array with 2 indices. However, is there an efficient way to use this from an array of objects and display key and value of each object in each of the columns.  For example using this as our wordCountArr state:

```
  const [wordCountArr, setWordCountArr] = useState([
    {"bingo": 2},
    {"bango": 5},
    {"needless": 1}
  ]);
```

Current way this is working in Hooks using an array of arrays. I would like to change the below state to match the above state

```
const App = () => {
  const [wordCountArr, setWordCountArr] = useState([
    ["bingo", 2],
    ["bango", 5],
    ["needless", 1]
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Word Count</h1>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Word</th>
            <th>Count</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {!!wordCountArr &&
            wordCountArr.map((wordArr, i) => (
              <tr>
                <td>{wordArr[0]}</td>
                <td>{wordArr[1]}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Your state would make more sense in the shape `[{label: 'bingo', value:2}, {label: 'bango', value:5}, ...]` otherwise you're just introducing more complex mapping for no gain over the tuples you're currrently using.

Comment: this seems like sensible approach and will give it a try